# Why my nodejs insert to mongoDB stops after a while

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am testing my nodejs insert to my MongoDB with following codes. When I insert for something like 10000 rows, everything works file. But if I tried insert something like 1 million, the insert action stops a while with no error printed out on nodejs console nor MongoDB.

I enclose my code and the console out of MongoDB below, please help me out, Thanks a lot!!

--- UPDATE ---

To answer questions from replies, I also checked my mongostat, and the insert stops after while. HOWEVER, I have observed two phenomenon:

1) on my laptop, whereby the mongodb parser is installed via "npm install mongodb", and the "node my.js" is started with following server output "Server has started."

Observed results: the insert is going on, mongostat shows that, most of the time the insert is zero, but sometimes inserted records can be show.

2) on my PC, whereby the mongodb parser is installed via "npm --registry http://registry.npmjs.eu/ install mongodb", and the "node my.js" is started with following server output "Server has started. -> Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version"

Observed results: the insert only runs for a while, then nothing happens, and mongostat shows always zero insert after a while.

Could the "npm --registry http://registry.npmjs.eu/ install mongodb" be a problem as well?

---

My nodejs code:

```
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb", { db : { native_parser : true } }, function(err, database) {

        if (err) { console.log(err.message); throw err; }

        // create new collection under database
        var collection = database.collection('gm_std_measurements_coveringindex');
        date = new Date();

        // add all Documents
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            var ranNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);

            // insert objects after table and index creation
            var istObject = {
                fkDataSeriesId : ranNumber,
                measDateUtc : date,
                measDateSite : date,
                project_id : ranNumber,
                measvalue : ranNumber,
                refMeas : false,
                reliability : 1.0
            };

            collection.insert(istObject, { w : 1 }, function(err, docs) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err.message);
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    // do noting to responsed inserted Document
                }
            });
        }
        console.log("* Documents created!");
    });
```

MongDB Server output:

```
Thu Apr 17 15:32:18.942 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:33228 #70 (3 connections now open)
Thu Apr 17 15:32:18.949 [conn70] end connection 127.0.0.1:33228 (2 connections now open)
Thu Apr 17 15:32:18.951 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:33229 #71 (3 connections now open)
Thu Apr 17 15:32:18.952 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:33230 #72 (4 connections now open)
Thu Apr 17 15:32:18.952 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:33231 #73 (5 connections now open)
Thu Apr 17 15:32:18.953 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:33232 #74 (6 connections now open)
Thu Apr 17 15:32:18.953 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:33233 #75 (7 connections now open)
Thu Apr 17 15:32:28.520 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/testdb.2, filling with zeroes...
Thu Apr 17 15:32:28.563 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/testdb.2, size: 256MB,  took 0.042 secs
Thu Apr 17 15:32:31.517 [conn75] insert testdb.gm_std_measurements_coveringindex ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:23 129ms
Thu Apr 17 15:32:31.517 [conn72] insert testdb.gm_std_measurements_coveringindex ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:37 129ms
Thu Apr 17 15:32:31.517 [conn74] insert testdb.gm_std_measurements_coveringindex ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:31 129ms
Thu Apr 17 15:32:31.517 [conn73] insert testdb.gm_std_measurements_coveringindex ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:19 129ms
```

Comment: You create a connection on each request, I think the number of connection is limited, this is the problem

Comment: Thanks for reply! I do not really understand, I think the "database" fetched from "mongoClient.connect" is a pool of connection, wherein the "collection.insert" inside the LOOP should reuse this connection pool internally?

If my understanding is wrong, how should the correct look like then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured it out myself somehow.

The issue of inserting of million of data from Nodejs into MongoDB is that, nodejs is so occupied by generating those records and send them out immediately. All the million of data appear immediately, and nodejs itself got stucked after a while, and at this moment MongoDB does not receive much incoming insert yet.

I "get rid of" this problem by setting a interval method which insert 10000 records at one time, and recall this interval every second, so that nodejs get the chance to move to its next 
event to send the generated inserts out, and then start the generation of inserts again.

```
interval_checkId = setInterval(createSomeInsert, 1000);
```

And the createSomeInsert method:

```
function createSomeInsert() {

    console.log("* Starting to insert another 10K records, current count: " + counter);

    var collection = dbPool.collection('gm_std_measurements_coveringindex');

    var date = new Date();
    var amount = 10 * 1000;
    for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {

        var ranNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);

        // insert objects after table and index creation
        var istObject = {
            fkDataSeriesId : ranNumber,
            measDateUtc : date,
            measDateSite : date,
            project_id : ranNumber,
            measvalue : ranNumber,
            refMeas : false,
            reliability : 1.0
        };

        collection.insert(istObject, { w : 0 }, function(err, docs){
            if(err) {console.log(err); throw err;}
            counter++;
        });

    }

    if(counter >= totalTarget) {
        clearInterval(interval_checkId);
        console.log("Completed Insert, in total : " + counter);
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

However, I still do not understand why nodejs will be blocked after many insert requests have been generated, and why most of them are not sent to mongodb in the background.

Answer (score -1):

you can use mongostat to check the progress of your script or see if anything is happening at all.

open cmd, navigate to /mongodb/bin dir and execute 
mongostat --host localhost

this will give you information what is currently happening with your mongodb server. the first column are the insert operations, which you have to check. this indicates how many items are inserted per second in the db. 
also look at the "locked db" column which shows you the write lock percentage of the database. higher percent means that write operations are being slower, because of the many inserts and each one is waiting for the previous to finish and unlock the db.
also be aware that connection.insert is asynchronous operation and basically you are trying to send 1 million insert requests to the database at once, because you are not waiting for any insert to finish.
i started your script 10minutes ago and i am currently at 400k items

Comment: hi @d1mitar, I answered your suggestion also in the question update. BTW, inserting 400k after 10 min, is it a little bit slow for nodejs and mongodb? -- I suppose my laptop (2G i7, 4G DDR3) has proven your results and it has similar results, -- really not as fast as i expected.

Comment: if you want to insert 1 milion records, you better put them in chunks by 10k for instance. it works for seconds on my machine. when you insert items one by one you are locking the database on each insert and it is really bad. for the mongodb it is a lot easier to insert 10000 items at once by passing an array to the collection.insert method, instead of adding one item at a time

Comment: True! For massive insert reality it should be Chunk insert. However, the scenario which I am simulating is a lot of requests from massive unknown clients at unpredictable time, that is why I am testing nodejs's capability answer massive single insert to MongoDB.